# sencha app - ios home screen icon turns black

Tags: ios, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm developing a sencha touch 2 app and I've set an icon for ios when it's needed to add to Home Screen. It works perfectly when you save it, but once you click it for the first time, the icon turns black completely, and it keeps like that forever, not being able to see my customized icon ever again. Text keeps perfectly fine.

Do you have any idea about this? Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue :(